# error crashing page even though I am using catch to render message to user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, try-catch

I have an api that sometimes it gives back a `500 error`

I am using a catch on it, so that if there is an error, I set a variable called `error` to `true`, and then, use that boolean to render an `error message component` if there was an error, or a react component called `FlightResults` if there was no error.

If there was a error, a variable called `flights`, wont be initialized.
That `flights` variable, goes in as props in the `FlightResults` component, and inside of it, it maps over it to render the flights.

So, if there was an error, I should be just rendering an error message component. which does not use the `flights` variable.

But still, the page crashes if there is an error.

What im I missing here? why even if I am conditionally rendering either the `error message component` or the `FlightResults`, when an error occurs, the page crashes saying it cant map over `flights` which is only used in the `FlightResults` component?

```
  const [error, setError] = useState(false)


  useEffect(() => {
    function filterResults() {
      setFilteredResults(results.filter(x =>  {
        return x.stars <= stars && x.price <= priceToFilter
      }))
    }
    filterResults();
  }, [priceToFilter, stars])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPirateApi(endpoint)
      .then( data => {
        setFilteredResults(data)
        setresults(data)
        const max = Math.max.apply(Math, data.map((x) => x.price ))
        setMaxPrice(max)
        setPriceToFilter(max)
      })
      .catch(e => {
        setError(true)
      })
    }, [endpoint])


  return (
    <div>
      {error
        ? (<p className="error">{errorText}</p>)
        : (<FlightResults flights={filteredResults} />)
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: How do you know that error is true? Did you check it in debugger?

Comment: Thoughts: In the second `useEffect()`, there's a sequence of statements each with side effect(s). 
It's possible that a later statement throws when one or more of the earlier side-effects is already committed.
If that's the cause of the problem then, in case of an error, you need to devise a mechanism, either (a) to withold side effects until you are certain that they will all be successful, or (b) to undo side effects already performed.